# Not able to get Windows and Anonymous Authentication working together

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, lifecycle

My previous question was that I was not able to find the windows authenticated user id during page load. The reason was because I had turned on Both Anonymous and Windows authentication in IIS. As per MMeasor's suggestion, when I turned off Anonymous authentication, It worked.

But my problem now is, I cannot do this. My application is a CMS application where anyone can access it. Only two pages of a particular folder are for Admin purposes that needs windows authentication. Currently I changed my IIS to have only windows Authentication. But how do I get the other pages Anonymous but still have windows authentication for the folder.

Below are my web.Config Details:

```
<configuration>
    <location path="_FolderPath">
          <system.web>
             <authorization>
                <allow users="?"/>
             </authorization>
          </system.web>
       </location>
</configuration>
```

and

```
<system.web>
 <authentication mode="Windows" >
     <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" cookieless="UseCookies" />
     </authentication>
          <authorization>
           <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Try to use System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; insted of Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")

Comment: use that or PrincipalContext

Comment: I tried but it actually doesn't matters because the pop-up that asks for credentials itself appears only after the page is loaded.

Comment: make sure anonymous authentication is off as well. you can't have both

Comment: That was a Good catch Mmeasor!! It worked!!  But now the problem is, I had windows authentication only for a particular folder. The rest of the site doesnt not need any authentication. i have updated my Question with the Web config settings. Now even my normal site is asking for authentication.